# How to fix showing notifications of filtered messages on apple watch?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am creating a Spam-SMS filter application with Xcode's built-in "Message Filter Extention" and it works really well.

There are no notifications in my iOS Device from those filtered messages but when it comes to apple watch all the notifications are still received.

I tried checking my apple watch notification setting and it is set on "iPhone mirror" so logically it should not display those filtered notifications as iOS Device doesn't show them.

Do you guys know how should I fix this issue?

Thank You.